# Initial subview rotation without animation in Swift

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, rotation, uilabel

I'd like to have a scaling animation in a subview (in this case it's a UILabel) but set an initial rotation without animating it. Problem is that it animates from that initial rotation back to 0 degrees.

```
        recordedTime?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)

        recordedTime?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi/180))

        view.addSubview(recordedTime!)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.50, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {

            recordedTime?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        }, completion:nil)
```

I suppose I could repeat the rotation transform in the animation, but that seems redundant, and my actual code is more complicated because it checks for my screen orientation, so I don't want that code repeated again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose I could repeat the rotation transform in the animation, but that seems redundant

But it's not redundant. Since the rotation and scaling of the view are encoded in the same `transform` property, you have no choice: you must always set the `transform` property to include both the rotation and scaling you want.

You can create properties to store the rotation and scale separately, and then compute `transform` based on those properties:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var recordedTime: UILabel!

    private var recordedTimeRotation: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet { updateRecordedTimeTransform() }
    }

    private var recordedTimeScale: CGFloat = 1 {
        didSet { updateRecordedTimeTransform() }
    }

    private func updateRecordedTimeTransform() {
        var transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
        transform = transform.rotated(by: recordedTimeRotation)
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: recordedTimeScale, y: recordedTimeScale)
        recordedTime?.transform = transform
    }

    private func run() {
        recordedTimeScale = 0.1
        recordedTimeRotation = .pi / 2
        view.addSubview(recordedTime!)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.50, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            recordedTimeScale = 1
        }, completion:nil)
    }

}
```